# Light sockets not lighting most bulbs

Tags: light, socket

We recently purchased a barn built in 1990. Only one of the bulbs was functioning, so I replaced the rest. They still wouldn’t light up so I replaced them again. Still nothing. I went through and pulled up the tabs in the bottom of all of the sockets. Still nothing. I moved the one bulb that had already been working to each socket and it, but only it, would light up. This one bulb- an emergency bulb with an E26 base- is the only bulb I can get to light in any of the sockets. I even bought new emergency bulbs, albeit from a different company since “ebulb” apparently no longer exists, but they would not work either.

To recap: I have a lot of sockets that will not light any bulbs except for one old ebulb, which seems to work just fine in every socket. Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Any dimmer, motion sensor, timer or anything else "special" about the switch(es) for these lights?

Comment: Are the new bulbs E 26 base also, or a different base?  Check the voltage/wattage of the light that works.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. When I was testing them with the one functional bulb, I simply had to flip each sockets’ respective switch. The only other piece of information I might have is that the one old bulb, though it did light up in every socket, was not particularly bright.

Comment: And yes, all the bulbs I have tried were also E26. And I’ve tried everything I could get my hands on -halogen, CFL, LED, flood lights, A21, etc.. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would take a meter reading of how much voltage the sockets have.  Old barn might have electrical problems.  Loose or chewed wires.

Comment: What type of bulbs?  Incandescent? CFL?  LED, long tube florescent?  This isn't rocket surgery, there is probably a bad connection somewhere.    One more question:  Are you saying there is a switch for each "socket" IE Fixture?

Comment: Crip659, unfortunately, given the state of the barn, I think chewed wires are a definite possibility. George- the bulbs that had originally been there were a mix of incandescent, CFL, and the one 9w ebulb. All the standard household bulb shape.  Presumably they all worked at some point, but I’ve long since thrown them all out. And yes, each room in this part of the barn (upstairs) has it’s own light socket (fixture) with it’s own corresponding switch. For what it’s worth, I didn’t have this problem in the downstairs. Just every socket/fixture upstairs.

Comment: What wattage is the working bulb vs. the other bulbs? What type is it vs. the others? Is it shining at its normal full brightness, or dimmer than expected? Low voltage might be enough to run several LEDs or one CFL or incandescent dimly, but adding more might bring it down to a level where no significant light is produced...

Comment: Take any or all NOT-working bulbs and try them in your home

Comment: Keshlam, the working bulb is only 9w, and it does seem a bit dim. I have tried other bulbs ranging from 8-60w. However, to your point, I’m not certain I have tried JUST a single other low wattage bulb- I might have only tried new bulbs while this one was on in an adjacent room. You think I might only be pulling enough voltage to run one very low wattage bulb?

Comment: Reason we're asking about shape is that incandescents typically have a slender first few inches above the base, and LEDs tend to immediately fan out to hold the electronics. This wide base often allows the screw threads to start, but then collides with physical bits of the fixture before the tip contact lands fully.  This gives you the feeling of "bottoming out in the socket" when you're really bottoming out against some obstruction.

Comment: 9W is pretty large these days, probably a 75 or 100-watt replacement. I can't say what the problem is, but if a single bulb works at all locations, that at least eliminates bad wiring as a potential cause...

Comment: @crip659 You actually couldn't see low voltage at a socket with a meter, even if the wire connection were barely made. A DMM's "load" is 10Mohms, and rural line voltage can fluctuate 10%. Therefore, the connection would have to present at least 1Mohms resistance to register, and if it had that much resistance, there's no physical way it could light a 9w bulb at all. You could measure the voltage drop _over_ the lit bulb to test wire quality, but it's (typically) not possible to reach both conductors when a bulb is present, unless you remove the assembly and probe the rear terminals...

Comment: I would try inlining [a bulb-to-plug+socket thingie](https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/fec53c4e-b7c3-4c94-a8e3-626872bed67f/svn/leviton-lamp-sockets-r52-01403-00w-64_1000.jpg) and trying again. This will ensure the physical bulb clearance harper mentioned, and allow a proper inline voltage test through the plug's holes, as crip659 alluded to. If it suddenly works, there's something funky about your physical socket (though tab-bending should likely have addressed that), and they might need replacing, but they are only a couple bucks each...

Comment: You said 'emergency bulb'. I'm not 100% sure of what that is. Any chance it's one with a battery in it that works on a circuit which has no power but a working switch? If that's the case look upstream to see if you're even getting power to the switch. The fact that a bulb of that type works in all the sockets likely clears the switch to socket wiring.